# What does the magnitude of a angular acceleration refer to?

Tags: math, rotation

The angular velocity changes from v_1 to v_2 over a time interval dt, where the angular velocity is in the form f * axis. Here, f represents the rate of spinning measured in radians per second, and axis indicates the axis around which the rotation occurs.

I calculate the angular acceleration using the formula (v_2 - v_1) / dt. Is this calculation accurate? If so, what does the magnitude of this angular acceleration signify?

Comment: v is usually used for velocity, which is a vector. Angular velocity is the tangential component of velocity about some axis, and is usually denoted as rw where r is the scalar distance from the axis where the motion is in a plane perpendicular to the axis, and w, lower Greek letter omega, is w = dtheta/dt where theta is the angle to the point in radians from the axis. I don't think 'angular acceleration' is a well recognised term, so you'll have to check the documentation of whatever you're working on to see what they mean by that.